# Adding more elements to nested array

Tags: php

If I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [item_id] => 2
            [quant] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 5
            [item_id] => 5
            [quant] => 6
        )

)
```

How can I keep adding elements to it to get this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [item_id] => 2
            [quant] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 5
            [item_id] => 5
            [quant] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 7
            [item_id] => 8
            [quant] => 9
        )

)
```

I have tried a few functions like array_merge and array_push, but with no success. The problem is treating each nested array individually when adding more arrays to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try just

```
$arr[] = array('user_id' => 9, 'item_id' => 10, 'quant' => 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array1 = array()
 $array2 = array();
```

if you want to append array2 to array1
   simply use

```
$array1[] = $array2;
```

or use array_push

```
array_push($array1,$array2);
```

see codepad http://codepad.org/x0T5CeXf

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go like this,

```
$array = array();

$obj = array('user_id' => 99, 'item_id' => 99, 'quant' => 99);

$array[] = $obj;
```

To simplify it you could create a function like so;

```
function addElement($element) {
     $array[] = $element;
}

addElement($obj);
```

If you had many objects to add this could make things simpler.